# how to open geotiff as base layer on openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geotiff-tiff

i want to add a geotiff image as base layer on openlayers :

- copy my image.tiff in a directory and open it with openlayers directly without using a cartography server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can turn the GeoTIFF files into an OpenLayers base map with the help of MapTiler software (http://www.maptiler.com/). Once the GeoTIFF file is processed with the software on your desktop - you get a directory with JPEG/PNG tiles together with a sample viewer made using OpenLayers.

Such a viewer and the folder with tiles can be uploaded to any web hosting - so there is no need to install any cartography server...

MapTiler either creates the Standard Mercator tiles - so your GeoTIFF can easily overlay Google Maps or OpenStreetMap, or it can keep the image in the original map coordinates.

If your file is a proper GeoTIFF with the geographical location and coordinate system definition embedded, then the software will load it automatically after you drag&drop it in - as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rSYFwcWVnc&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay&index=12

If you have a World file, but the coordinate system information is missing you can specify it easily: http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/coordinate-systems/

To turn an ordinary scanned maps without any location info into a map overlay see this video: http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/overlay-image-over-map/

Comment: It is quite nice, but is it possible to do this programmatically? How about converting hundreds of files at the same time?

Comment: Sure it is. See: http://www.maptiler.com/sdk/ and the manual for the command line usage: http://manual.maptiler.com/

Comment: In fact, we have in pre-release status a cluster version running on Amazon or Google cloud or on private clouds with Docker. This version is able to orchestrate a group of computers to render huge number of input files into a single seamless map (such as a detailed aerial photo of whole Texas or a stream of imagery from satellites - as done for our customers).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot do this.

You can only display those images using OpenLayers which are spported by browsers. That is why using `OpenLayers.Layer.Image` you can only display JPEG, PNG & GIF images.

Other Image formats like Erdas Imagine, Tiff, GeoTiff ASCII etc need to be converted to a format which browsers understand, before they can be shown in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [geotiff.js](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js) to load GeoTIFF from local storage or from URL. [Example with OpenLayers](https://github.com/pbabik/webraster)

Answer (score 0):

```
var map;
fetch('dem.tif')
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(async blob => {
        const dataurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        data = { minValue: 284, maxValue: 5976 }
        const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
            sources: [{
                url: dataurl,
                min: data.minValue,
                max: data.maxValue,
                nodata: 0,
            }]
        });
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
                    zIndex: 10000,
                    source: source,
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    zIndex: 0,
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [75.55294433275729, 32.9121361667626],
                zoom: 11,
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            }),
        });
    });
```